# Raspberry Pi OS for a project

Tags: raspbian, android

I have a project that will involve ultrasonic sensors, input interface(buttons, etc.), Audio output and a GPS shield (cooking hacks)

I would like to know whether i am better off using Android OS or stick with the Raspbian OS.

Comment: Raspbian is Debian Wheezy (a major GNU/Linux distribution) compiled for the pi's architecture; it was not designed just for the pi. While Android uses a tweaked linux kernel, the userland is much, much more limited.  I doubt anyone does any serious development in any language on **any** android device at this point in time.  No common C or C++ compiler will run on it, and neither will the normal python interpreter.  Etc.  If you are looking to do some programming, Android would be a complete waste of time.  *You can't even program for Android on Android* (but you could on debian...).

Comment: Android is toooooo slow to do any of this. Raspbian is also to slow because it is even drive, you will benefit from RiscOS which more real time driven. You could use Raspbian as the brain for processing but arudino or pic would be used to gather the data ontop in realtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raspbian is a known entity, and you will have no trouble finding existing tutorials and sample code for ultrasonic sensors and buttons or almost anything else you could want. This will make completing your project much easier. The same cannot be said for android on the Pi. As evidence of this the official download page for the Pi does not even list Android, and the FAQ page specifically says that it will not run on the Pi (though both of these facts may change with the new Pi model 2).

Comment: oh, and here i thought android might help make things easier. was i totally mistaken? If ever, can you recommend any OS that might be better for applications that involve the hardware i listed?

Comment: How would android make things easier? My recommendation would be Raspbian.

Comment: Steve's right. Raspbian is the way to go - program it in Python using the RPi.GPIO library.

Comment: oh, that reminds me. I am comfortable with C/C++ will that be a problem? i have read that C runs well on raspbian. i just want to confirm :)

Comment: you can totally use C, but more examples use Python (which is why i would recommended it)  though porting to C or calling a Python function/library  should not be an insurmountable challenge.